# .Displayed in C# throws when browser-testing on Android 8.0.0 via Appium 1.9.1

Tags: c#, android, appium

This code works fine against *Chrome* in local (i.e. on PC)...

```
IWebElement widget = Driver.FindElements(widgetLocator).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Displayed);
```

...but throws the following when used against **Appium 1.9.1** to talk to **Android 8.0.0**:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: unknown error: Argument to isShown must be of type Element
>     (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.90)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538

The browser does start up on Android, navigates to the page within our site that it's supposed to, and in most ways works fine. But, Displayed always throws the above without further explanation. Have anyone seen this?

I've tried using `ExecuteJavaScript()` to check visibility the hard way, but in `OpenQA.Selenium ExecuteJavaScript()` *returns void*, not `bool` as on other platforms. I've tried, Enabled but that doesn't do what I was after.  I've borrowed a colleague's `IsElementVisible()` function as below, but that throws as well:

```
public static bool IsElementVisible(IWebDriver driver, By locator)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    try
    {
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(locator));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And finally I've tried to `FindElement` on the element I'm looking for via `CssSelector`, `ClassName` and anything else I could think of, without success (they can't reliably only find the "visible" version of the element).

By way of background, what I'm trying to do here is to "port" some existing test scripts that work against Chrome on PC via *WebDriver* to test the same website on Android via Appium.  This legacy code uses . Displayed in many places and if I can't find a reliable alternative in the mobile situation we'll have somewhat of a problem.

Comment: @DaryHutchings it seems that you are passing only locator but not passing locator type is it xpath or id or class name like that

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code that i have edited
as you can see in your exception it says "Argument to isShown must be of type Element", it means what type of element you are passing please let us know if this solution worked

Exception:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: unknown error: Argument to isShown must be of type Element (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.90) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538
```

Code Edited:

```
public static bool IsElementVisible(IWebDriver driver, String locator)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    try
    {
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(locator)));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Appium WebDriver 4.0.0.4beta fixed the problem for me.